# Django saving model instance fails

Tags: django

For some reason I don't get this rather simple operation work.
I'm trying to save model instance to database (sqllite), but the saving fails with no error message (just showing 500, internal server error).
I have made my database with migrations (make migrations, migrate) and it should be up to date. So here is my view code:

```
post = Post(pub_date = datetime.datetime.now, image_url = " some url",  price = 0, item_id=1, description="some text", url=link)
post.save()
```

And here is are the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='posts')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)  
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="#")
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

`datetime.datetime.now` alone is a function and so you are trying to assign to `pub_date` a function, instead of function's value.